# .htaccess for sub domain SSL Error

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an SSL certificate on my main domain which is `https://www.example.com/`

There is also an .htaccess in the root folder which does all the rewrites to ensure the website is `https://www...`  and so on

But the problem I now have is each time I create a subdomain, an error is returned from google chrome saying: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This sounds almost like my subdomain is requesting to be identified as a https which I don't want it to. I understand my SSL certificate isn't a wildcard. I just want a subdomain to create a blog with. I have made a new folder with WordPress installation files and pointed to the folder, when I enter the address on Google chrome or any other browser, it does not even attempt to connect. I also noticed that even if I don't include 'www', and just type blog.domain.com, it gets rewritten into https  which leads me to believe I might have an .htaccess problem.

So I was thinking maybe the contents of my root htaccess file is responsible.

The content of my htc access file is below.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kwam-it.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.kwam-it.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: add `.htaccess` file code in question, not in comments.

Comment: That's because You've binded `subdomain.kwam-it.com` with SSL Certificate, but you might have not binded `www.subdomain.kwam-it.com`.

Comment: How do I unbind subdomain.kwam-it.com from the SSL?

Comment: That is based on what you are using as Cloud like, AWS, GCP, Azure or other.